# Filtered one-way synchronization of Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

We have a multi-tenant, single db application where some customers have expressed the desire to get direct access to their own data.

I have been suggested looking into Azure Data Sync to achieve a setup where each of the customers get their own Azure SQL instance to which we setup a one-way synchronization of their data from the master database.

I managed to find some documentation on this, but one I got around to try it out in a lab setup, it looks like the ability to filter rows in the sync job has been removed in a later iteration of the Azure Data Sync service.

Am I wrong or is that feature really gone? If so, what would be your suggestions to achieve something similar on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter rows using Azure SQL Data Sync. However, you can build a custom solution based on Sync Framework as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sync/2010/08/31/sql-server-to-sql-azure-synchronization-using-sync-framework-2-1/).

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a look. Not as "integrated" as I had hoped for :)

Looking at the two posts which that author has done, I can't help but feel that while I see the reason in what he's doing and how I might be able to go down that route, that it's for an entirely different scenario. Also, wouldn't it be difficult to get to run integrated in an Azure environment - and how to monitor it?

I've also been suggested doing it via Azure Data Factory. But again, it seems like a big solution for a rather isolated problem.

Comment: Try a product named SymmetricDS. It supports Azure SQL Database and can filter rows (using routers of type lookup, subselect, or BSH). http://www.symmetricds.org/